# Performance of TOP(1) select on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having a performance problem with a TOP(1) (or EXISTS) select statement on a join of 2 tables.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Records(
  Id PRIMARY KEY INT NOT NULL,
  User INT NOT NULL,
  RecordType INT NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Values(
  Id PRIMARY KEY BIGINT NOT NULL,
  RecordId INT NOT NULL,
  Field INT NOT NULL,
  Value NVARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Values_Record FOREIGN KEY(RecordId) REFERENCES Records(Id))
```

with indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Records ON Records(User ASC, RecordType ASC) INCLUDE(Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Values ON Values(RecordId ASC, Field ASC) INCLUDE(Value) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ValuesByVal ON Values(Field ASC, Value ASC) INCLUDE(RecordId)
```

The tables contain a lot of data, around 100 million records in Records and 150 million in Values, and they are still growing. Some users have a lot of data, some only a small amount.

For some user/field combination we might have no records in the Values table, but for some other user/field we have almost as many records in the Values table as we have in the Records table for that user.

I want to write a query testing if I have any data for a user/field combination. My first try was this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) V.Field
FROM Records R
INNER JOIN Values V ON V.RecordId = R.Id
WHERE R.User = @User
AND R.RecordType = @RecordType
AND V.Field = @Field
```

The problem with this query was, that if the execution plan was not in the server's cache and the first user did not have a lot of data, the server would put an execution plan for this query that did not work well for a user with a lot of data, resulting in a timeout (more than 15 seconds). The same problem occurred for RecordTypes or Fields. So I had to hardcode the id's in the query instead of using variables.

```
SELECT TOP(1) V.Field
FROM Records R
INNER JOIN Values V ON V.RecordId = R.Id
WHERE R.User = 123
AND R.RecordType = 45
AND V.Field = 67
```

But even then the server would sometime do a a table scan instead of using the available indexes, also resulting in timeouts. So i had to add FORCESEEK to the query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) V.Field
FROM Records R WITH (FORCESEEK)
INNER JOIN Values V WITH (FORCESEEK) ON V.RecordId = R.Id
WHERE R.User = 123
AND R.RecordType = 45
AND V.Field = 67
```

But even now, the server sometimes first seeks in the Records table and then in the Values table, instead of first seeking in the Values table and then in the Records table, also resulting in timeouts. I don't know why this result in a timeout, but it does. As fields are linked to a RecordType in my model, I could remove the RecordType clause, forcing the server of first seeking in the Values table

```
SELECT TOP(1) V.Field
FROM Records R WITH (FORCESEEK)
INNER JOIN Values V WITH (FORCESEEK) ON V.RecordId = R.Id
WHERE R.User = 123
AND V.Field = 67
```

With this last change I no longer have any timeouts, but still the query take around 1 to 2 seconds, sometimes even 5 to 7 seconds.

I still don't understand why this takes this much time.

Does anyone have any ideas how to improve this query to avoid these long querytimes ?

Comment: First you need to make it make sense. TOP without ORDER BY is going to return some indeterminable row so you should decide that first and introduce that to the query.

Comment: I'm using the TOP(1) as an EXISTS (both have the same execution plan), I don't care which row it returns, any row will do. Adding an ORDER BY forces the server to select all (thousands) rows complying with the WHERE clause and sorting them before executing the TOP statement.

Comment: You can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to recompile the query for the specific values being passed in.

Comment: If your table has widely skewed statistics, such that the normal histogram approach of the optimizer doesn't work, you may need to manually `UPDATE STATISTICS` with a higher `SAMPLE` value (or even `FULLSCAN`). You'll still need to avoid inappropriate cached plans (with `RECOMPILE`, per Gordon). Another approach is to manually split the `JOIN`: filter rows from one table into a temp table first, then join on that. This allows the optimizer to have accurate statistics (but may be much slower if the number of rows is in fact large).

Comment: I tried adding RECOMPILE in an earlier stage of the problem, but at the time it seemed to harsh as I only replaced one variable by a hardcoded value (user), but now I replace all variables, so the result would be the same.I already tried several UPDATE STATISTICS without avail, I never tried the FULLSCAN option, I will try it. But both suggestions don't change the fact, that even with the best execution plan the query takes several seconds, which seems long for such a simple query.

Comment: As always, if you don't know why a query is taking longer than you think it should, you'll have to get down to brass tacks and dissect the execution plans and the I/Os actually performed (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`) and number of rows actually read in each operator. If a query takes several seconds, then SQL Server is doing some work in those seconds. It doesn't matter how simple you think the query is -- consider the possibility that it just *isn't*, and you're assuming it is based on incorrect intuition. I've had several experiences like that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Should not make any difference but for grins try

```
SELECT TOP(1) 1
FROM Records R 
JOIN Values V  
  ON V.RecordId = R.Id
 AND R.User = 123
 AND R.RecordType = 45
 AND V.Field = 67
```